# Python and 1D spectrum - How to access data within fits file

Tags: python, arrays, astronomy, spectrum

I'm very new to Python and have been looking around for an answer I want but haven't found one. I have a 1D spectrum file (.fits) and would like to access its wavelength and flux information. For example, if I plug in a wavelength value I'm trying to write a program that would give me flux at the input wavelength. Could anyone give me a quick guide on how to write such a program, or what modules do I need to begin with? Will numpy and pyfits be enough to do the task? Thank you so much.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience reading this file format. If you're in a similar situation, you might find the [FITS Standard Document](http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/fits_standard.html) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I could find out from the FITS Standard, mentioned by Klaus, you would need PyFits and Numpy (Numpy is pre-requisite for PyFits). Get the MKL version for numpy 1.7

I downloaded this file: [HST FOS (FOS 2 x 2064 primary array spectrum containing the flux and wavelength arrays, plus a small table extension)](http://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/browse?file=/samples/FOSy19g0309t_c2f.fits), which containded the spectrum and wavelength. Now, I am not familiar with the format, but this is what I could find out:

```
import pyfits
hdulist = pyfits.open('testFits.fits')
tbdata = hdulist[1].data
```

`hdulist.info()` gave me this:
hdulist.info()

```
Filename: D:\Downloads\Documents\Python_Scripts\testFits.fits No.   
Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format 0    PRIMARY    
PrimaryHDU     163   (2064, 2)    float32    1    y19g0309t.c2h.tab 
TableHDU        85   2R x 19C     [D25.16, E15.7, E15.7, E15.7,
E15.7, D25.16, D25.16, I11, I11, D25.16, D25.16, A8, A8, I11, E15.7,
A4, E15.7, E15.7, E15.7]
```

Obviously, I could not make heads or tails of this :), so a bit more in depth:

```
print tbdata[0]
```

gave me:

```
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 2.738755e-15,
182.63573015259999, 39.405888372579994, 0, 0, 49099.133531036357, 49099.133541163668, 'PIXEL', 'SINGLE', 0, -1516.0, 'OBJ', 31.249689, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I am assuming this make sense to you.

```
print tbdata.columns
```

ColDefs(

```
    name = 'CRVAL1'; format = 'D25.16'; start = 1
    name = 'CRPIX1'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 29
    name = 'CD1_1'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 45
    name = 'DATAMIN'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 61
    name = 'DATAMAX'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 77
    name = 'RA_APER'; format = 'D25.16'; start = 93
    name = 'DEC_APER'; format = 'D25.16'; start = 121
    name = 'FILLCNT'; format = 'I11'; start = 149
    name = 'ERRCNT'; format = 'I11'; start = 161
    name = 'FPKTTIME'; format = 'D25.16'; start = 173
    name = 'LPKTTIME'; format = 'D25.16'; start = 201
    name = 'CTYPE1'; format = 'A8'; start = 229
    name = 'APER_POS'; format = 'A8'; start = 241
    name = 'PASS_DIR'; format = 'I11'; start = 253
    name = 'YPOS'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 265
    name = 'YTYPE'; format = 'A4'; start = 281
    name = 'EXPOSURE'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 289
    name = 'X_OFFSET'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 305
    name = 'Y_OFFSET'; format = 'E15.7'; start = 321
```

)

Now using those columns, you can make a module as:

1. take input flux
2. search columns for matching flux
3. show wavelength from matching row